# array one format to another

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array in two format. I want to change array from

```
Array
(
    [step_number] => 4
    [app_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )
    [formdata] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => app_id[]
                    [value] => 2
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => app_id[]
                    [value] => 3
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[2][2][]
                    [value] => 1
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[3][3][]
                    [value] => 200
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fieldval[3][3][]
                    [value] => day
                )
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [name] => title
                    [value] => new plan
                )
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [name] => feature_plan
                    [value] => 3
                )
            [7] => Array
                (
                    [name] => plan_type
                    [value] => free
                )
            [8] => Array
                (
                    [name] => price
                    [value] => 
                )
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [name] => sell_type
                    [value] => us
                )
       )
)
```

this format to

```
Array
(
    [app_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [fieldval] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 200
                            [1] => day
                        )

                )

        )

    [title] => new plan
    [feature_plan] => 3
    [plan_type] => free
    [price] => 
    [sell_type] => us
)
```

these are are one array into two format. i have data in to first array format and i want to change that format to second array type format.
please tell me how i am trying this for 2 days but not succeed.

Comment: what code have you tried? please add it to the question.

Comment: If you use var_export for your array dumps, it will make it easier to provide a solution.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent  `echo '<pre>';
  // $arr = array();
   
   $formdata = $_POST['formdata'];
   foreach($formdata as $key=>$val){
     $test = $val['name'];
  $$test = array();
     $$test = $val['value'];
  echo ${$test}; 
  //$arr[] = $$test;
  //array_push($$test,$val['value']);
  //echo str_replace('[]','',$$test);
   die;
  //print_r($$test); die;
  //$newarray = array_merge($arr, $$test);
  //print_r($arr); die;
   }
   print_r($arr);
   print_r($_POST); 
   die('kk');`
i have tried this or many more these type but not succed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function you could use to produce that conversion:

```
function convert_formdata($input) {    
    $output = array();
    foreach($input['formdata'] as $data) {
        $keys = preg_split("#[\[\]]+#", $data['name']);
        $value = $data['value'];
        $target = &$output;
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            // Get index for "[]" reference
            if ($key == '') $key = count($target);
            // Create the key in the parent array if not there yet
            if (!isset($target[$key])) $target[$key] = array();
            // Move pointer one level down the hierarchy
            $target = &$target[$key];
        }
        // Write the value at the pointer location
        $target = $value;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
$output = convert_formdata($input);
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/550249) for the given input. The output is:

```
array (
  'app_id' => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 3,
  ),
  'fieldval' => 
  array (
    2 => 
    array (
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => 1,
      ),
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      3 => 
      array (
        0 => 200,
        1 => 'day',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'title' => 'new plan,',
  'feature_plan' => 3,
  'plan_type' => 'free',
  'price' => NULL,
  'sell_type' => 'us',
)
```